# Nodejs: how to clone or duplicate an incoming soap http request?

Tags: node.js

My Node.js server receives http soap requests. I would like to clone/duplicate each requests in order to send one to server A and the other to server B. How can I do that? Thanks

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({changeOrigin: true});
app.all('/', (req, res) =>{
     // Duplicate or clone request
     // ..... and send it to server B

     // Forward original request to Server A
     proxy.web(req, res, { target: url_serverA }, function(e) {})
});
```

Comment: How do you say that a request is original or clone? Is not just only placing in two different lists?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: Luiz, clone or original, it does not matter which one goes to ServerA and Server B